# Why can't I install multiple packages at the same time? ("Unable to lock administration directory")

Tags: apt, software-installation

When I use root to do a job, why can't I do another one in another place like terminal or Ubuntu Software Center?

I receive this error message:

```
Unable to lock administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

[image: screenshot of terminal with apt commands and could not get lock errors]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no inherent reason you cannot do multiple jobs at the same time.

But some jobs are not meant to run at the same time. This is usually implemented by locking something.

In this case, you can imagine an update needing the current state of your machine, but it has to be sure nothing changed. If you are updating something (installing package X) and you run a different update that needs package X as well, it will ALSO try to install that package

Therefore, `apt` (or aptitude, or anything using the Ubuntu package system) should not run at the same time, and uses this `lock` file mechanism to check.